# Regular Expression to remove all numbers and all dots

Tags: regex, vb.net, numbers, extract

I have this code in VB.NET :

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace("Example 4.12.0.12", "\d", ""))
```

It removes/extracts numbers

I want also to remove dots

so I tried

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace("Example 4.12.0.12", "\d\.", ""))
```

but it keeps the numbers.

how to remove both (numbers & dots) from the string ?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a character group:

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace("Example 4.12.0.12", "[\d.]", ""))
```

I'll elaborate since I inadvertently posted essentially the same answer as Steven.

Given the input `"Example 4.12.0.12"`

- `"\d"` matches digits, so the replacement gives `"Example ..."`
- `"\d\."` matches a digit followed by a dot, so the replacement gives `"Example 112"`
- `"[\d.]"` matches anything that is a digit or a dot. As Steven said, it's not necessary to escape the dot inside the character group.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a character group using square brackets, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Regex.Replace("Example 4.12.0.12", "[\d.]", ""))
```

A character group means that any one of the characters listed in the group is considered a valid match.  Notice that, within the character group, you don't need to escape the `.` character.